# Summing up and concatenating the length of strings such that length of the strings meets a condition

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, tweepy

Suppose i have a list of strings and I wanted to make a tweet out of them. for example:

```
# should be two tweets total 
this_list = ["Today is monday tomorrow is tuesday the next" ,"will be friday and after that", "saturday followed by sunday", "this month is march the next", "april after that may followed", "by june then july then we", "have august then", "september and october finishing", "the year with november and december" ]
```

my desired output would be similar to this (stored in a list of course):

```
tweet 1:  'Today is monday tomorrow is tuesday the next will be friday and after that saturday followed by sunday this month is march the next april'
tweet 2:  'after that may followed by june then july then we have august then september and october finishing the year with november and december'
```

I have tried to use a while loop to achieve this but I am not sure the loop is working correctly...

```
out = [] # empty list
s = 0 # counter
tweet = "" # string to add too 
while s < 140:
    for x in this_list:
        tweet += x
        s += len(x)
    out.append(tweet)
print(len(out))
```

Comment: `tweet += x` - You are just adding the same word over and over until `s >= 140`. Try rearranging the `while` and `for` loops. Or maybe remove the `while`.

Comment: You are also not adding spaces between words and accounting for those spaces in the calculation of `s`.

Comment: Add some print statements in your code to see what is going wrong. You may solve your own problem.

Comment: made some updates @Johnny Mopp I originally accounted for that as well. Also twitter does not count white space as a character.

Comment: @blarg my best attempt got me close to the desired output; but it added the same word over and over like Johnny Mopp pointed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a list of tuples that held the length and text; then summing through the lengths until 140 characters met.

```
lot = [(len(i),i) for i in output] # list of tuples (length, txt)
out = [] # store tweets
y=0 # count len of tweets
t= '' # empty tweet 
for l, txt in lot:
    y += l
    t += txt
    if y >= 140:
        t= ''
        y = 0
    else:
        if y>= 119: # I want the 'full tweet' not building blocks
            print(t)
            out.append(t)

len(out) #number of tweets
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most pythonic way of doing this. But it is pretty clear and breaks down the logic in a visible manner:

```
mylist = ['Today', 'is', 'monday', 'tomorrow', 'is', 'tuesday', 'the', 'next', 'will', 'be', 'friday', 'and', 'after', 'that', 'saturday', 'followed', 'by', 'sunday', 'this', 'month', 'is', 'march', 'the', 'next', 'april', 'after', 'that', 'may', 'followed', 'by', 'june', 'then', 'july', 'then', 'we', 'have', 'august', 'then', 'september', 'and', 'october', 'finishing', 'the', 'year', 'with', 'november', 'and', 'december']

position = 0 #We keep track of the position, because we might reach the end of the list without meeting the 140 chars criteria
n_chars = 0 #character counting variable
list_of_tweets = []
iter_string = ''
for word in mylist:

    if(n_chars < 140): #We keep adding words to our sentence as max number of chars is not reached
        iter_string = iter_string + word + ' '
        n_chars = n_chars + len(word) + 1 #+1 because of the space we add
        if(n_chars >= 140):
                    list_of_tweets.append(iter_string[:-1]) #We delete the last char as it is a space
                    iter_string = ''
                    n_chars = 0

    if(position == len(mylist)-1):
        list_of_tweets.append(iter_string[:-1])

    position = position + 1 #We are advancing to the next word in the iteration

print(list_of_tweets)
```